# subversion 1.6.x losing changes on check-in

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to figure out if this is a known issue with SVN 1.6.x
Developer A modifies a file and commits it.
Developer B modifies the same file. Tries to commit it and gets told local copy out of date so does an update and then a commit.

However the changes from Developer A are lost so the resulting file only contains the version that Developer B checked in.

We can see this in the logs. It seems to happen when the same file is modified but in different places.

Anyone else experienced this? We've had it happen 4 or 5 times in the past few weeks and we've lost a half day or so each time trying to figure out what's been lost, etc.

We're starting to lose confidence in SVN. Should we be thinking of moving to GIT or Mercurial? Would that sort out this problem?

Comment: This is the basic multi-user use case of SVN, which is used by hundreds of thousands of developers without problems. It seems much more likely that the problem is something your users are doing.

Comment: I'm sorry to say "We're starting to lose confidence in SVN." you haven't understood how SVN works. Thats the point. If you make an svn update you will be informed if you have conflict. Than you have to solve that conflict. And SVN does not overwrite any changes and no changes will be lost.In the history the change of Dev A is in there. During the svn update a merge has happened. The Dev B should check if this is ok. If the situation is happening as you described there has been done something what you didn't wrote.

Comment: We know how to use SVN :) We've been using it daily for over 2 years...so this is a new thing.

Comment: It is also happening to me. Dev A adds a line and commit, Dev B modifies in other part of the file and update, the merge thinks B already had the line and had deleted it intentionally. I thought it might be that we were forgetting to save before updating but I can confirm that this problem evens occurs partially on some files, a part is merged right and a part lost. I had used SVN for 3-4 years without a problem until version 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Is anyone on your team copying files and folders around manually so that the revision info in the .svn folders is no longer correct?

As derobert describes in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344714/svn-says-i-need-to-perform-cleanup-but-the-cleanup-fails/344745#344745) to a related question, overwriting other users changes is possible if you manually copy your modified files into a newly updated SVN folder:

> Here is how the nuke/copy procedure can revert other people's changes:
>
> 1. Checkout, get r1;
> 2. Modify foo.c, giving r1 + changes;
> 3. Someone else checks in a change to foo.c (you don't know they've done
>    this, of course, and the normal way of
>    checking is broken for you), foo.c in
>    the repo is now r2;
> 4. You now nuke your repository except foo.c (r1 + changes);
> 5. You do a checkout, get foo.c r2.
> 6. You replace foo.c with your copy (r1 + changes). Subversion, however,
>    is unaware of this, and thinks you
>    based your changes on r2, not r1.
> 7. Checkin, foo.c is now r3, which has just lost the other person's
>    changes in r2.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget to save your file, then perform an 'svn update' (with whatever tool you like) and then save your local version of the file again over the updated file, then you lose the changes somebody else committed.

But this is **not** Subversions fault: **You** should save your changes and reload the files after updating. Most editors have features for this and if you use tools like Eclipse of Visual Studio you can look at integrated Subversion solutions to help you with this.

Comment: 1. the guy is saying that the SVN merge is broken. it is not the OP who doesn't know how to use SVN, but you who aren't taking the time to fully understand his question.

2. It is NEVER the user's fault when software is poorly designed. I recommend reading some Alan Cooper and Donald Norman books.

Comment: But if you mix and use several products, you can't blame just a single one of them for breaking your usage of the combination. Especially if one of the others wasn't designed to work together. I would recommend reading the manual of the products you use about how to use it instead of recommending reading about a different design patterns. The system was designed to work this way and so are the other version control systems. Switching to a different VCS or reading design books won't solve the problem.